# Stacking scatter_matrix and matshow

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, dataframe, correlation, scatter-plot

I was using the iris data from sci-kit-learn to obtain following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data= np.c_[iris['data'], iris['target']],
                     columns= iris['feature_names'] + ['target'])
```

Plotting the `scatter_matrix` and using `matshow` to plot the correlation matrix give me the graphs [scatter_matrix plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zzCX.png) and
[matshow(df.corr())](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6pzR.png), respectively.

My question is the following. Is there a way to stack these graphs? In other words, plot the `scatter_matrix` over the `matshow(df.corr())` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose what you really want is to colorize the background of the respective axes in the color that would appear in a matshow plot of the correlation matrix.

To this end we can find out the color by supplying the normalized (to 0..1) correlation matrix to a matplotlib colormap and change the axes background color using `ax.set_facecolor`.

```
import seaborn.apionly as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# taking the iris from seaborn (should be same as scikit)
df = sns.load_dataset("iris")

axes  =pd.scatter_matrix(df)
corr = df.corr().values
corr_norm = (corr-corr.min())/(corr.max()-corr.min())

for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    c = plt.cm.viridis(corr_norm.flatten()[i])
    ax.set_facecolor(c)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That is perfect. Thank you very much!